# org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jform-designer

I have integrate the JFormDesigner in my eclipse Version: 3.3.2, error that i faced is not completely in the subject as it is restricted with 150 characters.

So i have listed below:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jface.internal.text.html.BrowserInformationControl.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;IILjava/lang/String;)V)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4083)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3998)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:137)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
```

Above is the error log i face when i run a JPanel class which is converted to Java program from JFormDesigner.
My program run with no error but it does'nt show me the UI Frame.
I have been looking for the problem and also got some new result as.
delete files given below

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench\workbench.xml  
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.snap
```

But this did'nt solved my problem. I want to know is that something we need to take care when we are installing JFormDesigner plugin in Eclipse.

Can anyone have a solution. please let me know.

------------------Edited Part----------------------

Please find the code below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
/*
 * Created by JFormDesigner on Sun Aug 10 19:28:27 IST 2014
 */

public class StartUp_frm extends JPanel{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public StartUp_frm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        // JFormDesigner - Component initialization - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
        // Generated using JFormDesigner Evaluation license -  
        frame_startup = new JPanel();
        lbl_copyright = new JLabel();
        lbl_content = new JLabel();
        pbar_loading = new JProgressBar();
        lbl_welcomeText2 = new JLabel();
        lbl_welcomeText3 = new JLabel();
        label2 = new JLabel();

        //======== frame_startup ========
        {

            // JFormDesigner evaluation mark
            frame_startup.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder(
                    new javax.swing.border.TitledBorder(new javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0),
                            "JFormDesigner Evaluation", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER,
                            javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.BOTTOM, new java.awt.Font("Dialog", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 12),
                            java.awt.Color.red), frame_startup.getBorder())); frame_startup.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener(){public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent e){if("border".equals(e.getPropertyName()))throw new RuntimeException();}});

                            frame_startup.setLayout(null);

                            //---- lbl_copyright ----
                            lbl_copyright.setText("copyright tANiapps");
                            lbl_copyright.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                            lbl_copyright.setEnabled(false);
                            frame_startup.add(lbl_copyright);
                            lbl_copyright.setBounds(290, 240, 150, 39);

                            //---- lbl_content ----
                            lbl_content.setText("load changing contents");
                            lbl_content.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                            lbl_content.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 22));
                            frame_startup.add(lbl_content);
                            lbl_content.setBounds(40, 180, 365, 50);

                            //---- pbar_loading ----
                            pbar_loading.setBackground(Color.red);
                            frame_startup.add(pbar_loading);
                            pbar_loading.setBounds(10, 140, 420, 30);

                            //---- lbl_welcomeText2 ----
                            lbl_welcomeText2.setText("FASHION GARAGE ");
                            lbl_welcomeText2.setFont(new Font("Bradley Hand ITC", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 22));
                            lbl_welcomeText2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                            frame_startup.add(lbl_welcomeText2);
                            lbl_welcomeText2.setBounds(65, 50, 335, 50);

                            //---- lbl_welcomeText3 ----
                            lbl_welcomeText3.setText("to StickyStock ");
                            lbl_welcomeText3.setFont(new Font("Bradley Hand ITC", Font.BOLD, 22));
                            lbl_welcomeText3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                            frame_startup.add(lbl_welcomeText3);
                            lbl_welcomeText3.setBounds(90, 85, 260, 50);

                            //---- label2 ----
                            label2.setText("Welcome, ");
                            label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                            label2.setFont(new Font("Bradley Hand ITC", Font.BOLD, 22));
                            frame_startup.add(label2);
                            label2.setBounds(105, 25, 235, 30);

                            { // compute preferred size
                                Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension();
                                for(int i = 0; i < frame_startup.getComponentCount(); i++) {
                                    Rectangle bounds = frame_startup.getComponent(i).getBounds();
                                    preferredSize.width = Math.max(bounds.x + bounds.width, preferredSize.width);
                                    preferredSize.height = Math.max(bounds.y + bounds.height, preferredSize.height);
                                }
                                Insets insets = frame_startup.getInsets();
                                preferredSize.width += insets.right;
                                preferredSize.height += insets.bottom;
                                frame_startup.setMinimumSize(preferredSize);
                                frame_startup.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
                            }
        }
        // JFormDesigner - End of component initialization  //GEN-END:initComponents
    }

    // JFormDesigner - Variables declaration - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:variables
    // Generated using JFormDesigner Evaluation license -  
    private JPanel frame_startup;
    private JLabel lbl_copyright;
    private JLabel lbl_content;
    private static JProgressBar pbar_loading;
    private JLabel lbl_welcomeText2;
    private JLabel lbl_welcomeText3;
    private JLabel label2;
    // JFormDesigner - End of variables declaration  //GEN-END:variables

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StartUp_frm obj = new StartUp_frm();

        //pbar_loading code

        /*Thread t = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while (i <= 100) {
                    pbar_loading.setValue(i);
                    try {
                        sleep(90);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        System.out.println("pbar_loading problem : " + ex);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();*/
    }
}
```

this is a converted code from JFormDesigner. When i run this, no output with zero error. It should atleast show me the designed GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The code is trying to find a constructor

```
public BrowserInformationControl(Shell parent, int shellStyle, int style, String statusFieldText)
```

for the internal class `org.eclipse.jface.internal.text.html.BrowserInformationControl`. This used to exist in older versions of Eclipse including 3.3 but is not present in later versions.

You need to run using a old version of Eclipse which has this version of `BrowserInformationControl` or update to code which is more up to date.

Since `BrowserInformationControl` is an internal class this code is violating the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) and is consequently not safe to run on different versions of Eclipse.

Comment: thanx..so this may be a problem..can i install this as external jar..and solve my problem..as i have converted all of my form with JFormDesigner..it will be time taking to design again.. #greg-449

Comment: I'm not very clear exactly what you are running but I don't think an external jars is going to work.

Comment: Please any one can help on this.i am still confused.i am normally designing code in JFormDesigner and converting and running in eclipse. #greg-449